# import all variables of parent class

Tags: c++, gcc, templates, scope

You may have notice that later versions of gcc is more strict with standards ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605497/accessing-inherited-variable-from-templated-parent-class))

All inherited members of a template class should be called using the full name, ie. 
    `ParentClass<T>::member` instead of just `member`

But still I have a lot of old code that does not respect this. Adding `using ParentClass<T>::member` for each used member in each class is quite a pain. Is there is a way to do something like `using ParentClass<T>::*` ?. I would like this better than deactivating this check in g++ but if there is now way, how can I deactivate it ?

**Edit**:

According to C++ FAQ (thanks sth) these are the only way to correctly solve the inherited member variable names :

1. Change the call from `f()` to `this->f()`. Since this is always implicitly dependent in a template, `this->f` is dependent and the lookup is therefore deferred until the template is actually instantiated, at which point all base classes are considered.
2. Insert `using B<T>::f`; just prior to calling `f()`.
3. Change the call from f() to `B<T>::f()`.

So now looking for the right switch to deactivate the full name resolution ...

Answer (score 6):

Not really an answer to you question, but you [can also write](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19) `this->member` instead of `ParentClass<T>::member`. This is most often easier to write and makes the compiler look for `member` in the right places.