# Protected member of templated superclass should be visible in subclass, but (sometimes) isn’t

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing inherited variable from templated parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605497/accessing-inherited-variable-from-templated-parent-class)

I have been implementing a binary heap as a subclass of priority_queue, and run into a situation I cannot understand, despite considerable effort. Here is the **working** version of the code. (Background: `c` is priority_queue’s backing vector.)

```
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

template <class nodetype>
class BinaryHeap : public priority_queue<int> {
public:
    BinaryHeap() { vec = &c; }
    vector<nodetype> *vec;
};

int main() {
    BinaryHeap<int> b;
}
```

However, when you change the superclass to:

```
class BinaryHeap : public priority_queue<nodetype>
```

...the compiler complains about the usage of `c`:

```
h.cpp: In constructor ‘BinaryHeap<nodetype>::BinaryHeap()’:
h.cpp:10: error: ‘c’ was not declared in this scope
```

This seems all the more strange because:

1. “[c] is equivalent to this->c” ([ref](http://ben.am/eH)) – and if you use `vec = &this->c`, it does indeed compile.
2. If you add a using-declaration, `using priority_queue<nodetype>::c` to BinaryHeap, again, it compiles. But this using-declaration ought to be unnecessary.

**Edit:**

So, apparently this happens because “the compiler does not look in dependent base classes when looking up nondependent names” ([ref](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19)) – “`c`” does not depend on a template parameter, and so is nondependent, and `priority_queue<nodetype>` does depend on a template parameter – `nodetype` – so is dependent.

`priority_queue<int>`, on the other hand, doesn’t depend on `nodetype`, and so is nondependent, and so the compiler *does* look in it for names when resolving other nondependent names.

Is this correct? And if so:

Why does the standard mandate this behaviour, when “[looking] in dependent base classes when looking up nondependent names” is clearly *possible*. What is the benefit? A compile-time performance optimisation?

Comment: See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19.

Comment: Thanks Oli. How unspeakably dreadful.

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate. The other question is about compilers’ compliance to the standard: “Do the new Gnu C++ compiler obey the standard or not?” This is about the code problem itself: *why is the using declaration necessary*.

Comment: Perhaps.  But there will many other questions on precisely this topic...

Comment: Also, I have to say, I floundered around trying to find the answer to this for a long time, on SO & elsewhere, with no luck. I try hard not to create SO questions lightly – this is a hard thing to solve, both through Googling and SO, and this Q could save someone encountering this problem a good deal of time.

Comment: Please cite the standard, not IBM documentation.

Comment: Now that the actual question is answered: why would anybody want to do something like this? If you want to use std::priority_queue's logic you could just use std::make_heap(), std::pop_heap(), and std::push_heap(). None of the containers in the standard C++ library is intended to be derived from. You can reasonably ask why there are protected members but I'd think this was an error in a couple of classes nobody paid close attention to.

Comment: @DietmarKühl To make a dynamic heap container – one where you can update nodes in O(logn) time. It is actually a common, and nice, way to do it. [See here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/tic/tic0229.shtml) for examples. All you need do is implement up_heap, down_heap and update functions. (The exposing of `c` as public is a performance optimisation for initialisation – directly editing the vector and then re-sorting it with `make_heap` is O(n), whereas filling it using `push` is O(nlogn). I agree it’s slightly iffy, but does not seem problematic in practice.)

Comment: Well guys, I respect your opinions that this a duplicate, but I must say I disagree. After my edits, this Q now asks: 1. “What is the behaviour” and 2. “What is the benefit to this behaviour”, which are both distinct from 3. “What compilers comply with the standard”. Furthermore, even were it a duplicate, it seems against the spirit of SO to close a Q that is more detailed and, I think, better written, leaving a less informative and descriptive Q the canonical one.

Comment: @Benji XVI: I'd still think that it would be better to not derive from std::priority_queue and implement the few functions using the STL algorithms for the actual logic. Also, I don't buy into the argument for the initial set up requiring access to the internal container: std::priority_queue can be constructed from a range. However, I had missed that std::make_heap() actually only takes O(n) time.

Comment: @DietmarKühl (Yeah, it’s a handy fact: creating a heap by sorting is faster than pushing values on one by one.) You make good points, but I can’t think of a single practical disadvantage to subclassing PQ. Can you give a specific way it “would be better” not to? (The upside is you don’t even need to write wrappers for `pop`, `push`, `empty`, `size`, & `top` – you get ’em all free.)

Comment: @BenjibXVI: sure: std::unique_ptr<std::priority_queue<int>>(new BinaryHeap<int>()); looks like a reasonable thing to do (well, between construction and deallocation you'd probably do something) but causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end its simply a matter of the standard defining such a behaviour for templates. The (C++11) standard says the following about non dependent name resolution in **[temp.nondep] (14.6.3)** :

> Non-dependent names used in a template deﬁnition are found using the usual name lookup and bound at the point they are used.

Since `c` doesn't obviously depend on a template parameter the compiler treats it as a non-dependent name. So what happens is basically the following: When the compiler looks at `BinaryHeap` the actual type of `notetype` is unknown and therefore `priority_queue<nodetype>` is too, since it depends on `nodetype` (it could be a partial specialization). Therefore the compiler can't look into that type for the resolution (since we are talking about the point where the template is defined, not where it is instantiated). So it looks in the containing scopes for something called `c`, finding none and therefore rejecting the code.  Using `this->c` (or `using priority_queue<nodetype>::c`) makes `c` a dependent name (since its not a member of `BinaryHeap` it must be a member of `priority_queue<nodetype>`), so the name lookup is delayed until the point of instantiation of the template, where `notetype` is known and the compiler can therefore search in `priority_queue<nodetype>`.

For your edit: yes, that is correct

Comment: *When the compiler looks at BinaryHeap the actual type of notetype is unknown* – My understanding is that templated classes are compiled on demand, once instantiated. Therefore the compiler does, definitely, know the type of nodetype. Indeed, multiple versions of a templated class/fn will be compiled, each time a new instantiation with a different type is encountered.

Comment: @BenjiXVI: There are phases, though. Case in point: dependent types

Comment: @Benji XVI: As I mentioned in the end the reason is that this is the behaviour mandated by the standard. This allows the compiler to do some part of the compilation when encountering the template instead of when instantiating it. As Lightness Races in Orbit mentioned the compiler does the compilation in several phases.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yes, point taken.

Comment: @Grizzly Thanks, makes sense! Maybe move “[It] allows the compiler to do some part of the compilation when encountering the template instead of when instantiating it” into the answer – it would seem to be!