# Can't call inherited protected generic class members

Tags: c++, templates, generics, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing inherited variable from templated parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605497/accessing-inherited-variable-from-templated-parent-class)

There's this class:

```
template<typename T> class Parser
{
    public:
        Parser() : count(0) {}
        virtual void parse(const string&);
    protected:
        virtual void get_token(void);

        char token;
        string expression;
        int count;
};
```

and I made this derived class:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Parser.h"

template <typename T> class ArithmeticExpressionParser : public Parser<T>
{
    public:
        ArithmeticExpressionParser() : Parser<T>() {}
    protected:
        virtual T parse_plus_minus();
        virtual T parse_divide_multiply()
        {
            T result , temp;
            result = parse_exponent();

            if(this.token == '/')
            {
                temp = parse_divide_multiply();
                result /= temp;
            }

            else if(token == '*')
            {
                temp = parse_divide_multiply();
                result *= temp;
            }

            else if(token == '%')
            {
                temp = parse_divide_multiply();
                result %= temp;
            }

            return result;
        }

        /* more code.... */
```

Now the errors I'm getting are:

./include/ArithmeticExpressionParser.h|45|**error: there are no arguments to ‘get_token’ that depend on a template parameter**, so a declaration of ‘get_token’ must be available [-fpermissive]|

./include/ArithmeticExpressionParser.h|25|**error: ‘token’ was not declared in this scope**|

etc. etc.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `this->token`.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: See the duplicate question. Basically, the compiler doesn't know that `token` is a dependant name, as such you need to tell it that.

Comment: thanks again. I'll give the last close vote.