# visibility of a nested class in an inherited class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, visibility, nested-class

The code I work on is roughly the following:

```
// List.h
template <typename T> class List{
    template <typename TT> class Node;
    Node<T> *head;
    /* (...) */
    template <bool D> class iterator1{
        protected: Node<T> this->n;
        public: iterator1( Node<T> *nn ) { n = nn }
        /* (...) */
    };
    template <bool D> class iterator2 : public iterator1<D>{
        public:
        iterator2( Node<T> *nn ) : iterator1<D>( nn ) {}
        void fun( Node<T> *nn ) { n = nn; }
        /* (...) */
    };
};
```

( should the exact code of the above one be needed, please refer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852772/error-inherited-class-field-undeclared-according-to-g) )

```
// Matrix.h
#include "List.h"
template <typename T>
class Matrix : List<T> {
    /* (...) - some fields */
    class element {
        supervised_frame<1> *source; // line#15
        /* (...) - some methods */
    };
};
```

I get the following error in g++:

```
 In file included from main.cpp:2:
 Matrix.h:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘supervised_frame’ with no type
 Matrix.h:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
```

Comment: There's not enough code here to pinpoint an error. At a guess, however, you need to forward declare `supervised_frame<int>`.

Comment: @Yuushi please refer to the link provided. There is List.h which I include in the above code and where supervised_frame is defined.

Comment: Whoever upvoted this question, why? It's completely nonsensical as-is. @infoholic_anonymous : Please see http://sscce.org/; making the people you want help from do all the work isn't productive.

Comment: @ildjarn The title makes it perfectly clear in my opinion. He really should have included a short definition of `List` though.

Comment: @Pubby Thanks for the remark, I've done what you've suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `Matrix<T>::element` class is not related to class `List<T>`. So I think you should have `typename List<T>::template supervised_frame<1>`.

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous,OK, then I think it needs to be `typename List<T>::template supervised_frame<1>` . This is to let the compiler know that the 2nd "<" is a bracket and not a less-than.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to your previous problem - Use `typename List<T>::supervised_frame<1> *source;` This is because `supervised_frame<1>` is a dependant type, i.e it is dependant on the template parameter `T`