# Inheritance of class members, mixed with templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, member

in the code below, why does T2 give this error `‘m_t’ was not declared in this scope`, while TB is fine ?

And how can I have access to T1's members in T2 while still using templates ?

```
// All good
class TA
{
    public:
      TA() {}

    protected:
    int m_t;
};

class TB : public TA
{
    public:
      TB() {}

      int get()
      { return m_t; }

    protected:
};

// Error in T2
template<typename T>
class T1
{
    public:
      T1() {}

    protected:
    int m_t;
};

template<typename T>
class T2 : public T1<T>
{
    public:
      T2() {}

      int get()
      { return m_t; }

    protected:
};
```

Comment: Try `this->m_t`. It is about the two phase lookup and dependent names.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/605497/951890

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `this->m_t` to make it a dependent name. When templates are compiled, names are looked up in two stages. Non-dependent names are looked up when the compiler first parses the template. Dependent names are looked up when the template is instantiated. Changing it to `this->m_t` delays look-up until after the `get` function is actually instantiated, in which case the base class type is known and the compiler can verify the member's existence.

Comment: Im a bit disappointed because inheritance doesnt seem as practical now. But thanks it works.