# Inheritance of templated class members in constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, constructor

I posted a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420012/inheritance-of-class-members-mixed-with-templates) and got my answer. I'm now facing the same issue with the constructor.. 
How would one write the constructor for T2 ?

```
template<typename T>
class T1
{
    public:
      T1(int t) : m_t(t) {}

    protected:
    int m_t;
};

template<typename T>
class T2 : public T1<T>
{
    public:
      T2(int t) : m_t(t) {} // error

      int get()
      { return this->m_t; }

    protected:
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call the base class constructor in the initializer list for `T2`:

```
T2(int t) : T1<T>(t) {}
```

`T2<T>`'s constructor will call `T1<T>`'s constructor, which will initialize `T1<T>::m_t`