# inheriting template class c++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Problem with inheritance and templates my derived class doesn't recognize x which is a member variable in my base class.

```
 template <class type>
 class one
 {
 public:
 type getX();
 type x;
 };

 template <class type>
 type one<type>::getX()
 {
 return x;
 }



 template <class type>
 class two: public one <type>
 {
 public:
 type getX();
 };

 template <class type>
 type two<type>::getX()
 {
   return x;
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing inherited variable from templated parent class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605497/accessing-inherited-variable-from-templated-parent-class)

Comment: See also: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html

Comment: why does this awful qst come up as the #2 search result on google?

Answer (score 1):

Since `two` is a template, and `x` is not direct a member of two, you need to make explicit the dependency.

One way is `one<type>::x`, another can be `this->x`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "this->" for accessing template base class member & functions inside template parent class.

return this->x;